# if id is given, how do i find the other values of other attributes in this list with dictionaries inside

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, list, python-3.8

```
my_playlists=[
    {"id":1,"name":"Bicycle Playlist","numberOfSongs":3},
    {"id":2,"name":"Coding Playlist","numberOfSongs":2}
]
```

if the input is 1, which is supposed to be considered as an id. how do I get the name attribute? and its value?

Comment: lets say the id is 1, how can I get BIcycle Playlist printed?

Comment: iterate over the list and check the `id`. Or better - convert the list of dicts to dict of dicts

Comment: conversion of data types is not allowed in the assignment that I was given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using for loop

```
for i in my_playlists:         
    if i.get('id') == 1:       
        print(i.get('name'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension as:

```
my_playlists=[
    {"id":1,"name":"Bicycle Playlist","numberOfSongs":3},
    {"id":2,"name":"Coding Playlist","numberOfSongs":2}
]

inp_id = 1
res = [elt['name'] for elt in my_playlists if elt['id'] == inp_id][0]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
Bicycle Playlist
```

Comment: don't use `id` as name

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
>>> my_playlists=[
...     {"id":1,"name":"Bicycle Playlist","numberOfSongs":3},
...     {"id":2,"name":"Coding Playlist","numberOfSongs":2}
... ]
>>> 
>>> next(item for item in my_playlists if item["id"] == 1).get('name')
'Bicycle Playlist'
>>>
```

Comment: what is next? my compiler is just blank at the output when I tried to run this

Comment: @JaveedYara https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next

Answer (score 0):

> try this:

```
my_playlists=[
{"id":1,"name":"Bicycle Playlist","numberOfSongs":3},
{"id":2,"name":"Coding Playlist","numberOfSongs":2}
]
Id = 1
for j in my_playlists:
    if j.get('id') == Id:
        print(j.get('name'))
```